# I am getting Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection error. What wrong with my image upload?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using `react-native-image-picker` to select image from the phone and upload it but I am getting the error.

Here what I am doing.

First I select the image from image libarary
here the code for that

```
const handleChoosePhoto = () => {
        launchImageLibrary({}, response => {
            if (response) {
                console.log(response)
                setPhoto(response);
            }
        });
    };
```

And here is the log from the console from above code. I got the image `fileName, fileSize, uri, type` etc.

```
{"assets": [{"fileName": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_965f2731-46de-4db3-ba56-f6b5c5bbe26a.jpg", "fileSize": 145447, "height": 1280, "type": "image/jpeg", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.bac.bad/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_965f2731-46de-4db3-ba56-f6b5c5bbe26a.jpg", "width": 960}]}
```

So there is nothing wrong with it.
The problem  is that when I try to upload it. I am getting this error

```
**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection error**
```

Here How I write the image upload.

Here is the form append logic.Since I save response handleChoosePhoto I can get the data back from the state.

```
const createFormData = photo => {
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('files', {
        name: photo?.assets[0]?.fileName,
        type: photo?.assets[0]?.type,
        uri: photo?.assets[0]?.uri,
    });

    return data;
};
```

and here is the upload api call

```
const handleUploadPhoto = () => {
        axios
            .post(
                'userapi/UpdateUserProfileImage',
                {
                    body: createFormData(photo)
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                },
            )
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.Message));
    };
```

I always get the error log `Index is out of range` Error.

When I test in postman I only get this `Index is out of range` error when I don't pass parameter to the api when I calling the api.

So I think that the file is not attached to the formData when try to append it.
How can I solve this?